# Nginx response size

Tags: http, tcp, nginx, response

how can I emulate bad connection in nginx server? I want to test client to receive all data not in one package, but with splitting into few packages.

Maybe, I can set the size of response package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at: [limit_rate](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#limit_rate)

If you set it to a fraction of the total response size, nginx splits it into several packets.